# Open directory in server side and open files inside it

Tags: php

I have a directory inside my server full of PDF files and I would like to open the file and be able to click on the name of the PDF and watch its content.  Now I only get the names of the files in a list but thats all.  I would like to press in the name and open the PDF.

```
<?php 
$sub = ($_GET['dir']); 
$path = 'pedidos/'; 
$path = $path . "$sub"; 
$dh = opendir($path); 
$i=1; 
while (($file = readdir($dh)) !==   false) {
  if($file != "." && $file != "..") {
      if (substr($file, -4, -3) =="."){
          echo "$i. $file <br />";
      }else{                  
          echo "$i. <a href='?dir=$sub/$file'>$file</a><br />";
      }
      $i++;
   } } 
closedir($dh); ?>
```

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php

Answer (score 1):

I modified your code and works for me:

```
<?php
$sub = ($_GET['dir']);
$path = 'machotes/';
$path = $path . "$sub";
$dh = opendir($path);
$i=1;
while (($file = readdir($dh)) !==   false) {
    if($file != "." && $file != "..") {
        if (substr($file, -4, -3) =="."){
            echo "$i. <a href='$path/$file'>$file</a><br />";
        }
        $i++;
    }
}
closedir($dh);
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

your URL in the a href seems to be wrong try:

```
echo "$i. <a href='$path/$file'>$file</a><br />";
```

just make sure that $path is the correct relative path

this will link to the actual pdf file allowing the users pdf reader to get to it it will NOT parse and display the pdf using php

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer.   I have try the change you propose me and I am still not able to click in the PDF files .  It just shows the list of them.   But thanks a lot.

Comment: <?php
$path = "pedidos/";
$dh = opendir($path);
$i=1;
while (($file = readdir($dh)) !== false) {
if($file != "." && $file != "..") {
    echo "$i. <a href='$path/$file'>$file</a><br />";
$i++;
}
}
closedir($dh);
?>